# Clipping very large polygon datasets in ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-10.0

I'm attempting to clip a large polygon dataset (~5gb, thousands of features) by a much smaller polygon dataset (~40 features). Is there a best practice or most efficient route for performing this task?

The standard [geoprocessor clip](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//000800000004000000.htm) runs indefinitely on a dataset of this size. Would some form of spatial selection and export be more efficient?

**EDIT**: Some great answers below. I selected what I view to be the most thorough response, but each answer provides unique insight into the issue. Thanks!

Comment: How does the extent of the smaller dataset compare to that of the larger one?  If the extents are very different, have you considered first clipping (or merely selecting via intersection) the large dataset with the *extent* of the smaller one to reduce the size of the problem?

Comment: Clipping very large polygon datasets in ArcGIS? Don't do it. After many years of trying this we end up using a database and get SQL the work, time is money.

Comment: @whuber - +1 The extents are quite similar, although I've used your suggested method in the past.

Comment: Too bad... I agree heartily with Mapperz.  I also see @dmahr has posted a very nice reply that should help you sneak up on a solution or work-around, if one is possible.  It provides a good strategy for dealing with any large dataset using any software.

Comment: From this blog it seems to be quite problematic in ArcGIS. http://donmeltz.com/blog/index.php/2011/06/11/arcgis-vs-qgis-clipping-contest-rematch/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As always when dealing with scalability problems, it's best to start small and simple and steadily work your way up to big and complex.

In the case of clip, it should be smart enough to deal with big datasets because [it tiles them internally](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Tiled_processing_of_large_datasets/000800000014000000/).  But since it's not working, try running Clip with the input dataset (the data to be clipped) and the clip dataset (the data with which the clip is performed) **with many, many fewer features**.  Like one clip feature, with only the area around it in the input dataset (use definition queries to shrink them).  Make sure that it's running okay, and then steadily increase the scope of the geoprocessing operation until performance degrades.

A couple specific ideas:

- Dissolve the clip features into a single, multi-part feature class.
- Reduce the file size of the input features using [Simplify Polygon](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//007000000011000000).  A 5GB vector dataset is enormous--even a shapefile of all 250,000 US Census block groups is only about 1GB.
- Split the input features into parts.  Theoretically the internal tiling routines within the geoprocessing tool should be doing this already, but you never know.  There may be some 32-bit file size limitation issue where you can't have a shapefile bigger than 2<sup>32</sup> bytes = 4.29GB.

Some other, more general geoprocessing performance tips:

- Make sure both datasets have the same coordinate system.  If possible, it's faster to have both in a geographic coordinate system with no projection.
- Make sure you are not running off of a network drive.  Use the fastest local hard drive or, if possible, an SSD.
- [Load the clip dataset into memory](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//002w0000005s000000).
- Delete unnecessary attribute fields (and rejoin them later if needed).
- [Other geoprocessing performance tips](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//002v0000000v000000.htm).

Comment: +1 Very nice.  Might I suggest approaching the problem a little more quantitatively?  Rather than just waiting for the onset of performance degradation, take the opportunity to time the operations.  Even something as crude as watching the system clock can be useful.  Plotting time against the size of the problem can indicate how it scales, give you a way to extrapolate the effort to the full problem, and even reveal places where the scaling changes (you hit a resource wall or the internal algorithm changes, for instance).  It's easy information to get and can be very useful.

Comment: I totally agree with Whuber on this.  I always keep track of geoprocessing performance time, especially with timedelta objects in Python (when I'm scripting with ArcPy).  Another tip is to use a more fully featured system monitor, like [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653).  This can give you **much** more information about performance and help you identify bottlenecks.

Answer (score 8):

Or, you could give up on ArcGIS and try doing the clip in OGR. See an explanation [here](http://darrencope.com/2011/03/31/clipping-large-shapefiles-using-ogr/). I've found this works when nothing else does!

Comment: ogr2ogr -clipsrc clipping_polygon.shp output.shp input.shp


Damn, that is beautiful.

Answer (score 7):

Some ArcGIS functions like Union and Intersect use **adaptive subdivision processing** as described in [Tiled processing of large datasets](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//000800000014000000.htm).  Unfortunately it appears as though *Clip* does not have a large geoprocessing tool.

It seems like you might be able to replicate this concept via a ModelBuilder or Python script that uses the [Split tool (ArcInfo)](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//000800000006000000.htm) to help process oversized datasets.

Answer (score 3):

I think even select by location will work for you, first you select all the polygon which intersect with your smaller shapefile and then delete them. hopefully this might be quicker. lemme know if it works out for you. Thanks.

Comment: Not a bad idea in general--but did you read the comments to the original question?  The preliminary query is not going to reduce the size of the problem much.

Comment: This really works for me. And, by the way, this is quite different than clipping to the extent. I have two vector files (one with >7 million features, and another with ~5000) with the same extent, but with fewer than 1% of those 7 million features intersecting the clip features. I waited more than 8 hours for the clip to work on the full dataset...it never finished before I gave up. Instead, I selected by location the intersecting features, exported the selection to its own feature class, and then ran the clip. Total time for this (including the selection): about 1.5 minutes.

Comment: It's a good choice for clipping points by polygons as in my case. I tried to clip about 1 million points by 1 million polygons - let it run over two days and it never finished. Select by location and export was done in less than 5 minutes. I don't know why I didn't think of this option in the first place :-)