# Limitations when running the Union tool with large datasets?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, performance, union

*I'm running ArcGIS 10.3 with an Advanced License on a Windows 7 64x system with 20 GB of RAM and a 4th Gen Intel i7 Quadcore-CPU.*

I have a problem with the normally very efficient `Union` tool. **What I'd like to achieve** is a simple union of two feature classes in order to fill holes in my main feature class, say *"flat areas" (blue)*. I therefore created a large surrounding polygon *"union polygon" (green)*. The below images explain the situation (overview and zoomed in):

[image: overview]
[image: detail]

My blue feature class is large (60 MB), but not huge. It was created combining different features, then I ran the `dissolve` and `buffer` tools on it.

**The problem now is** that when I try to unify the two feature classes, ArcCatalog returns **"Error 999999: Error executing Function. Invalid topology"**. I have read [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/19622/clipping-very-large-polygon-datasets-in-arcgis/19624#19624) about processing large data and followed as many of the instructions as possible:

- No network drive
- SSD
- dissolved polgons

So finally my **questions**:

- Does anyone have an idea what could cause the problem? Hardware issue?
- Any further tipps or recommendations about the `Union` tool?
- Or even better - an alternative in order to fill the holes in the "flat areas" feature class?

---

**Update:**

I've meanwhile found this post: [Invalid Topology [Topoengine error] from ArcGIS for Desktop?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/60250/invalid-topology-topoengine-error-arcgis-10-1) which seems to be about the same problem as I'm experiencing, however there isn't a solution either. I'm currently running the `Repair Geometry` tool.

Also I've tried to run `identity` instead of `union` since that would also work for my task. The same error showed again.

Comment: Have you run check geometry tool to see if your data has invalid self intersecting data?

Comment: Thanks @Hornbydd for your remark. This lead me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My question is probably a duplicate of the following two questions:

- [Invalid Topology [Topoengine error] from ArcGIS for Desktop?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/60250/invalid-topology-topoengine-error-arcgis-10-1)
- [Clipping very large polygon datasets in ArcGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/19622/clipping-very-large-polygon-datasets-in-arcgis/19624#19624)

However, I will try to summarise the problem into one answer in order to have a complete overview of the problem and its solution:

**Possible Cause:**

- When creating large polygon layers (through tools in the `Analysis Toolbox`) ArcGIS might create *tiles* due to a maximum number of nodes in polygons. These tiles are prone to topology errors.

**Preparations:**

- Work on a local drive, if possible SSD
- Try to use dissolved polygons
- Simplify polygons if possible
- Check whether you might be able to perform the tool `in_memory` (depends on your hardware and the size of your feature class)
- Delete uncessesary fields in the feature classes

**Solution:**

1. Reboot machine, Restart ArcCatalog, don't use ArcMap for the task
2. Use the `Repair Geometry` tool (data management toolbox), try again
3. Copy your data to a new FGDB, try again
4. Split your features to be processed into smaller parts, try again
5. Upgrade hardware, try again